# Unknown syntax error when trying to nest if statement inside of a do while loop

Tags: c, visual-studio, if-statement

I am writing a program that reads in a number that the user enters, checks to see if it is between 0 and 100, if it is then the number is square rooted. If the number is less than 0, an error message is printed. If the number is between 100 and 200 then the natural log of the number is found and if it is over 200 then the loop terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{
     float num;
     double x, y;

    do {
        printf("Please enter a number \n");
        scanf("%f", &num);

        if (num > 0 && num <= 100)
        {
            x = sqrt(num);
            printf("The square root of the number entered is %f \n", x);
        }
        else if (num <= 0)
        {
            printf("Please enter a positive number \n");
        }
        else (num > 100)
        {
             y = log(num);
             printf("The natural log of the number entered is %f \n", y);
        } 
    } while (num <= 200);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having, is when I build the solution, I get an error statement saying that a ; is expected after the

```
else (num > 100)
```

What is the reason for this as I would not expect there to be one needed here?

Comment: Why are you mixing `float` with `double`? In the year 2016 please use `double` unless there is a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

```
else (num > 100)
```

should  be

```
else if (num > 100)
```

`else` clause doesn't any condition - it's just a syntax error.

You should also check if `scanf()` call succeeded:

```
if (scanf("%f", &num) != 1) {
   printf("Input error");
   exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`else` does not take an *expression*, it is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the syntax.

The format is

> `if` `(` expression `)` statement `else` statement

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.4.1

> [...] the first substatement is executed if the *expression* compares unequal to 0.
>   In the `else` form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not
>   executed.

So, to check for *another* condition, you need to have another `if` clause.

Compile your code with warnings enabled and you'll get to see a compiler screaming like

> warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
>            `else (num > 100)`
>             `^`